# openpyxl won't save if the file is opening?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

THis is my code:

```
filePath = 'D:/test/test01.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filePath)
source = wb['Template']     
target = wb.copy_worksheet(source)
wb.save(filePath)
```

I am trying to copy a worksheet named Template in the same workbook, if the file is opening, this script doesn't work and give an error "permissionError:[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/test/test01.xlsx'". But if I close the xlsx file, this all works fine. why this happened?

Comment: "But if I close the xlsx file" you mean from excel? it's expected as excel locks the xlsx file (using windows file lock)

Comment: Yes, means I close it from excel. Do you mean if the file opens in the excel, it would be considered as locked? So I cannot modify it with the script? But how can I solve this problem?